# Deezer content is served over HTTP

Tags: javascript, deezer

I am using Deezer Javascript SDK and loaded it over https.

```
<script src="https://cdns-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js"></script>
```

But from today Chrome and Firefox has problem, because Deezer SDK loading some script over https and Chrome rejected as insecure content.

Chrome console:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://....' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.deezer.com/js_trad-v00340851.php?l=cs'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
playerBB.php:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://....' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/core-v00340851.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
playerBB.php:1 Mixed Content: The page at '...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/live-v00340851.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 9):

This happens when your page and remote resource are using different `HTTP` protocols: one uses `HTTP` and another uses `HTTPS`.

The preferred way to include third-party scripts is this one:

```
<script src="//cdns-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js"></script>
```

Removing `https:` or `http:` tells browser to load the document using same protocol as current page. This should eliminate security warnings.

Comment: I am using https for all scripts, but Deezer script is loading another scripts over http if I loaded a dz.js over https. I think that is a problem.

Comment: @user2700047 ... You cannot go up in security ... so you cannot jump from http to https ... so if they only use http does it work if you yourself start from http so the download would go from http to http whilst using the above src="//someurl trick

Answer (score 0):

when i set the url : 
`<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/download/1.txt"></a>` from a https request, it report error : 
Mixed Content: The page at `'https://127.0.0.1/index.html'` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource `'http://127.0.0.1:8080/download/1.txt'`. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

when i added the `target="_blank"` to the url: `<a target="_blank" href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/download/1.txt">`, it works! , it works! 
it's well known that `target="_blank"` means opening the linked document in a new window or tab or a new request!