# How do I load a Web Worker script over HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I am attempting to use a Web Worker to offload some CPU intensive calculations into a separate thread. For a little context, I am taking an audio stream from `getUserMedia` and saving it into a file to be uploaded to my service after it is complete. I am able to retrieve the stream from the user and play it back via the WebAudio API and through an HTML5 player, but now I need to take the next step of saving it into a file.

**The problem**:

My main service is running over an HTTPS connection, since it is restricted to signed in users only. I have a worker script that does what I need it to, and I am attempting to load the script in via a relative path into my worker. I am receiving the following error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://someurl.com:1081/some/path' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure Worker script 
'http://someurl.com/some/path/lib/assets/javascripts/worker.js'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I figured it was because I was using a relative path in my code like so:

```
worker = new Worker('lib/assets/javascripts/worker.js');
```

I wanted to rule this out so I made the following change:

```
worker = new Worker('https://someurl.com:1081/some/path/lib/assets/javascripts/worker.js');
```

This did not solve my error. It appears that the `Worker` is loading my script via HTTP no matter what url location I attempt to use. I couldn't find any reference on how to use the Web Worker via HTTPS, so I am hoping someone can provide some insight.

**Possible Solution**

I do want you to know there is a possible solution, but it seems a bit *hacky* to me. I can load my worker script up as a `Blob` and pass that directly into the `Worker`. If this is the only solution, I can make it work. But I was hoping to find a way to make the script load via HTTPS.

Comment: Is your host page `https`?

Comment: Odd.  I'd say to look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see exactly what resources and protocol the browser is requesting to see if that gives you a hint where the problem is.

Comment: I can see the request in the network tab, and the request URL is the `https` one. It is highlighted red and says canceled (I assume because of the error message saying that the request was blocked). There is no other data in the headers.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page so we can look in the debugger ourselves?  Also, did you post the error message in your question exactly as it said because that shows `https://someurl.com:1081` for the page protocol/domain/port but `http://someurl.com` for the webWorker script protocol/domain/port which are not the same in protocol or port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. The error itself was misleading and caused me to go down a rabbit hole looking for the solution.

The issue here actually stems from the way I have this service configured. The service that starts the web worker is actually proxied behind another service, and all requests go through the parent service. This works great for most requests, but was causing an error in this case. Instead of forwarding the request on this port to my app, the web worker was attempting to download the worker script from the parent service itself. This means the error stemmed from the fact that the script wasn't found, not that the protocol was incorrect.

To solve this, I had to pass in a localized script location from Rails using its asset pipeline. This allowed the worker to grab the script and actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
//someurl.com:1081/some/path/lib/assets/javascripts/worker.js
```

instead of

```
https://someurl.com:1081/some/path/lib/assets/javascripts/worker.js
```

Just something I found here,
[Deezer content is served over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965975/deezer-content-is-served-over-http)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this gave the same error. It did help me track down what was actually happening though :)

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad you figured it out.