# Loading Deezer Javascript SDK over https times out

Tags: javascript, https, deezer

Loading the Deezer Javascript SDK over http from http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js works fine, but when trying to download it over https from https://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js, the request times out, both in the browser and with e.g. `curl`. Based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966043/305436), I understood that the SDK should be available over https too, so is there some problem with the SDK hosting?

Comment: I guess SDK just not available through https at all. Previous answer provided a way to include 3rd party library, but you have no guarantee, that it will be available through https. The solution will be to load this librarty to the hosting, which could serve it through HTTPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the docs, it is written that the url for `https` should be https://cdns-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js

Note the `s` at the end of `cdns`.
You can check this information [here](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah good, cdns-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js works with both http and https, but cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js only works with http.