# Create blob over https

Tags: javascript, ssl, web-worker

I'm attempting to move an existing application behind nginx for ssl termination and load balancing between two servers. The app works fine currently, but when behind ssl I get an error about a web worker I'm creating from a blob.

*Edit to clarify*
Running the node server with ssl also causes this. I'm not loading it from an external resource, the page itself is creating it via a script that was also fetched over https.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure Worker script 'blob:null/7dc18b31-c49c-48c5-b76f-443a1a9b459f'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The worker is created at the page that was loaded over https, here is the creation code.

```
var blobUrl;
try {
  blobUrl = new Blob([blobCode], {type: 'application/javascript'});
} catch (e) {
  window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder
    || window.WebKitBlobBuilder
    || window.MozBlobBuilder;
  blobUrl = new BlobBuilder();
  blobUrl.append(blobCode);
  blobUrl = blobUrl.getBlob();
}

var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blobUrl));
```

Is there a way to create a web worker from a blob and get it to load over https?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deezer content is served over HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965975/deezer-content-is-served-over-http)

Comment: I've read both posts and this is not a duplicate.

Comment: It looks like the problem is the `blob:null` part of the url created by `URL.createObjectUrl`. You might be able to set the correct protocol using `URLUtils.protocol`, although that interface seems to only be supported in Firefox, according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/protocol).

Comment: Looks like it is a bug inside Chrome as referenced [here.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437440&q=mixed%20content%20blob&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)